# Read page's linked script from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension with the ability to detect custom javascript code from a Browser Action.

So far, I managed to detect when the custom code is in the page itself, but I can't detect it when it is loaded from an external .js file (and that's the purpose of this question, I want to detect the content of a `<script src="http://www.externaldomain.com/file.js"></script>`

I know this could be achieved since Google did it in its "Tag Assistant" extension but checking their source code, everything is minified and it's hard to figure out how they did it.
[eg. Tag Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63X7Y.png)

Do you have any idea of which API/trick they used ?

Comment: Can't close-vote, but I would say that it's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by "custom javascript"?

Comment: Let's say I want to find a specific expression like "var myVariable ="

Comment: Find? Find where? For instance, you can add a `<script>` tag that sets `myVariable` then deletes itself from the DOM. The variable will be set, but that line of code no longer exists.

Comment: I want to find any code inside an external javascript (<script src="http://www.externaldomain.com/file.js">) as Tag Assistant does it.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to reflect that (and the requirement not to redownload).

Comment: Done.Regarding the redownload, it looks like TagAssistant DOESt redownload the file but doesn't run the code inside but I can't understand how it's made

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "from a Browser Action"? In the popup? On click?

Comment: Forget about the browser action part. We can focus on a minimal case and do this from the content script

Answer (score 1):

When a website loads up, it runs all the scripts kind of like the console on chrome.  if you run `alert("hello")` using the console,it will run once, and you will have no way to get it back using javascript. Similarily, embedded js files are all run once, and you can't just look into the html or anywhere else to get the code back since the js file is unloaded after being run. All the functions are stored in variables, events linked to those functions, etcetera.

What you can do, and probably will have to do is re-fetch those files using ajax.

I think that is exactly what tag assistant does.
After looking for a while I found this:

```
//for each document.script, get the src, and load it with ajax using the function gf(src,return function), and send the response.responseText to the text identification functions
cf.prototype.qa = function(a, b) {
    var c = {};
    Ea(document.scripts, function(d) {//for each
        !d.src || "" == d.src || c[d.src] || ef(this, d.src) || d.src == a || (c[d.src] = !0, gf(d.src, function(a) {
            cf.M().W.forEach(function(c) {
                c.u() && (c = c.qa(a.responseText, d.src), c.length && b(c, d.src))
            })
        }))
    }, this)
};
```

function gf is a simple ajax call with a callback function

```
gf = function(a, b) {
    try {
        var c = new XMLHttpRequest;
        c.open("GET", a, !0);
        var d = !1;
        c.onreadystatechange = function() {
            d || 4 != c.readyState || 200 != c.status || (d = !0, b(c))
        };
        c.send()
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

source from [chrome-extension://kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk/tag_assistant.js](http://(chrome-extension://kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk/tag_assistant.js)) (the content script)

Seeing what tag assistant does, I suggest you get every script element, retrieve its src,and in your content scripts, run a simple ajax call like the one on this page: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855

```
//for each script, get its src,and do whatever you want with it
for(i=0;i<document.scripts.length;i++){
    load(document.scripts[i].src, function(xhr){
       myCodeAnalyzingFunction(xhr.responseText)
    })
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I came across too but looking at their code, it looks like they are able to retrieve every external tag. But when I try I always have a CORS error popping up. In their code however, it seems like they are able to make the request without having any issue. Do you have any idea of what is done in their code to do that ?

Comment: It might have to do with one of their permissions, and if that doesn't work, both your background.js and popup pages can access cross-origin pages without issues.

Comment: You need host permissions. Look that up in the documentation - `"<all_urls>"` will suit your purposes. And like I said in the comment on the question - if a script was added as a tag and then removed, you can't recover it.

Comment: Giving the bounty to @Thouartamazing. Can't find a way to do that from the page itselft though (like it's done in tag assistant)